# Manually give rep to users, to thank them

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, appreciation

I recently made [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18522574/198633) to which I got [this **very** detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523553/198633).

I'm very appreciative of the fact that the user took so much time to write up such a comprehensive answer and would like to give them some of my rep.
Granted, he's at 53k rep and doesn't need the little extra he'll get from me, but I still want to show my appreciation; and stalking him to find his address to send him a basket of muffins is a little too creepy, even for me.

Now, I could start a bounty, but there are three problems with doing that:

1. I'm not looking for a better answer
2. If I were to start a bounty, I'd have to be fair and consider all new answers as well, before awarding it
3. The posted answer has been posted as a community wiki, so I'm not sure that he'd even get the bounty if I awarded it to his post.

So short of reading all his posts that I can understand to upvote him a lot (so he'll get the +5/10 rep for each one), is there a way that I can give him some of my own rep (*a la* manual bounty award) as a "thank you"?
Note that I'd have to be really careful if I choose to go down the serial voting path, so as not to trip the "suspicious voting" script [[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23842/190564)]

PS: I've already looked at [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23841/190564) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117455/need-a-new-award-bounty) and they're not duplicates of this question

Comment: You can explicitly start a bounty to award to an existing answer.

Comment: *"The posted answer has been posted as a community wiki, so I'm not sure that he'd even get the bounty if I awarded it to his post."* - He would. Problem solved.

Comment: See [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065) for how bounties and CW answers interact.

Comment: @Bart: how would I do that? Would I just start a bounty like usual and award it to an existing answer after 1 day (this is a problem, as mentioned in (2))?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget There is a bounty reason solely dedicated to rewarding an existing answer. It's unlikely that other users would contribute additional answers seeing that reason in the notice. That *is* the method that you're supposed to use, and no other method will be implemented.

Comment: Start a bounty and select "Reward existing answer" as the bounty reason @inspectorG4dget. That option explicitly states *"One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."*

Comment: But... muffins... they're so tasty :(